# Help in building Yocto(open embedded) projects using cluster computing in Linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, cluster, syslinux, yocto

I need to reduce project build time in [Yocto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yocto_Project) (open embedded) in Linux platform. So I decided to cluster computers for the best performance for compilation and building.

My question:
Is there any MPI which best suits this scenario?

Comment: Welcome to U&L. We want complete, self contained answers here on this site, so asking for links (or reference materials) is inappropriate.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am working on a new MPI platform, but this won't work for this scenario, because so far I understand, you have a lot of `shared memory`.

Maybe it could help you `openmp` with multithreading for `local parallelism` and according to my experience, for parallelism through the `network`, `OpenMPI` is the best choice and well documented for `linux distributions`.

P.S. Could you describe more the parallelism requirements?

Comment: First, thank you for the answer. My requirement is, I need to build source files parallel using yocto with Linux based computers connected through network and final output to the master computer.

Comment: Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14472175/distributed-compile-with-bitbake

Comment: @GokulTechno Ok, then you require a lot of `shared memory`. As Frank did mention, it is possible to use parallel build (using local parallelism). I don't have experience with `yocto`, however, according to my experience I recommend you to start trying to compile each header and source file per CPU and then join all precompiled files into the final binary on the master computer. Probably you will need to wirte a brief `MP interface`.